# equations arranged in a table like with text

Tags: equations

[image]

Hi all,

Could you please give me some help in writing the equation 22.2 show in the image. It is an image from Feyman's book, and I could not figure out how to write it.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5):

A modification of Henri Menke's answer, with a few adjustments (and simpler than Mico's). Mainly some vertical space between items, but also a slightly raised index for the root.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional, just for full emulation

\begin{document}

The direct and inverse operations are summarized as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} r l @{\qquad} r l @{} }
(a) & addition       & (a$'$) & subtraction \\
    & $a+b=c$        &        & $b=c-a$ \\
\addlinespace
(b) & multiplication & (b$'$) & division \\
    & $ab=c$         &        & $b=c/a$ \\
\addlinespace
(c) & power          & (c$'$) & root \\
    & $b^a=c$        &        & $b=\sqrt[\uproot3 a]{c}$ \\
\addlinespace
(d) & power          & (d$'$) & logarithm \\
    & $a^b=c$        &        & $b=\log_{a} c$
\end{tabular}
\end{equation}

Now here is the idea. These relationships…

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use an `array` and number the items by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{rl@{\hspace{3em}}rl}
    \text{(a)} & \text{addition}       & \text{(a')} & \text{subtraction} \\
               & a + b = c             &             & b = c -a           \\
    \text{(b)} & \text{multiplication} & \text{(b')} & \text{division}    \\
               & ab = c                &             & b = c/a            \\
    \text{(c)} & \text{power}          & \text{(c')} & \text{root}        \\
               & b^a = c               &             & b = \sqrt[a]{c}    \\
    \text{(d)} & \text{power}          & \text{(d')} & \text{logarithm}   \\
               & a^b = c               &             & b = \log_a c       \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use a `tabular` inside the equation, as suggested in the comments.  Then you only have to include the formulae in `$...$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{tabular}{rl@{\hspace{3em}}rl}
    (a) & addition       & (a') & subtraction       \\
        & $a + b = c$    &      & $b = c -a$        \\
    (b) & multiplication & (b') & division          \\
        & $ab = c$       &      & $b = c/a$         \\
    (c) & power          & (c') & root              \\
        & $b^a = c$      &      & $b = \sqrt[a]{c}$ \\
    (d) & power          & (d') & logarithm         \\
        & $a^b = c$      &      & $b = \log_a c$    \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `tabular` to get rid of all those `\text`s, since they appear more frequently than math formulas.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that's quite similar to the one taken in [Henri Menke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558250/5001), with the following two main differences: (a) I use `\textup` rather than `\text`, to guard against the possibility that the equation will be typeset in a theorem-like environment (which renders text in italics by default), and (b) I insert extra vertical space between the four main groups.

I also suggest using `$'$` to generate "prime"-type accents rather than text-mode apostrophes, as is also done in the screenshot you posted, and distinguishing more explicitly between the two "power" relationships: I'd call one "polynomial" and the other "exponential".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman font
\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{@{} ll @{\hspace{1.5cm}} ll @{}}
  \textup{(a)} & \textup{addition} & \textup{(a$'$)} & \textup{subtraction} \\
       & a + b = c& & b = c-a \\[1ex]
  \textup{(b)} & \textup{multiplication} & \textup{(b$'$)} & \textup{division}\\
       & ab = c   & & b = c/a \\[1ex]
  \textup{(c)} & \textup{polynomial} & \textup{(c$'$)} & \textup{root}  \\
       & b^a = c  & & b = \sqrt[\uproot{3}\leftroot{1}a]{c}\\[1ex]
  \textup{(d)} & \textup{exponential} & \textup{(d$'$)} & \textup{logarithm} \\
       & a^b = c  & & b = \log_a c 
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ah, the idea is to use an array with 4 columns, divided into 2 sets of cols and a big space between them.

Comment: @NguyenVinhPhu - That's correct. Just in case it wasn't obvious: The space of `1.5cm` was a bit arbitrary -- feel free to adjust the amount of spacing to suit your needs.